# Odd UITableView tableviewheader changing header height after scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

this is an odd behaviour I came across and for the life of me can not see where it is happening.

Context, new UITableViewController with 100 rows all saying test. I put another controller view as the tableHeaderView as below. It correctly says the height to be 200. It displays it correctly. Nothing wrong so far.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _header.view;
```

Now when I scroll, I would like to check the height of the header to show and hide the header depending how much is in view.

```
- (void)showHideHeader:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    NSLog(@"%@",@(offset.y));
    if (offset.y < _header.view.bounds.size.height){
        if (offset.y > _header.view.bounds.size.height * 0.75) {
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        } else {
            [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Logging the views at the start and when they are at the scroll method reveals 2 different heights. No other code is in this new table controller.

```
    (lldb) po _header.view
<UIView: 0x7fdf524b18a0; frame = (0 0; 320 200); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdf524b0de0>>

(lldb) po self.tableView.tableHeaderView
<UIView: 0x7fdf524b18a0; frame = (0 0; 320 200); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdf524b0de0>>
```

Then when I log it at the scroll

```
(lldb) po _header.view
<UIView: 0x7fdf524b18a0; frame = (0 0; 320 58); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdf524b0de0>>

(lldb) po self.tableView.tableHeaderView
<UIView: 0x7fdf524b18a0; frame = (0 0; 320 58); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdf524b0de0>>
```

Any ideas what may be causing this strange change?

edit: posting code for more information, nothing in the header so just posting the main.

```
#import "MyCallsBaseTableViewController.h"
#import "MyCallsBaseTableHeaderViewController.h"

@interface MyCallsBaseTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyCallsBaseTableHeaderViewController *header;
@end

@implementation MyCallsBaseTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!_header){
        _header = [[MyCallsBaseTableHeaderViewController alloc]init];
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _header.view;
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, _header.view.bounds.size.height);
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 100;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"TEST";

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - scrollview delegates

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self showHideHeader:scrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    [self showHideHeader:scrollView];
}

- (void)showHideHeader:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    if (offset.y < _header.view.bounds.size.height){
        if (offset.y > _header.view.bounds.size.height * 0.75) {
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        } else {
            [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
        }
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: post the code to initialization of _header.view

Comment: posted the .m, the .h is the standard uitableviewcontroller initial creation

Comment: This seems really strange. You are setting the header view to an instance of itself? Maybe I'm wrong but seems strange. Start with using a generic view for your header. UIView *v = [UIView... And once that's working I would move your header view to its own class

Comment: Nice idea and yeah sure enough it kept the height. So I subclassed UIView instead of UIViewController and it seems fine. However, is having UIViewController's view not allowed? it does get properly added, just strange behaviour.